# Multiple elements sharing the same positive tabindex value?

Tags: accessibility, tabindex

I have multiple elements in my form , having tabindex as 1 for all....
How should it behave?
What should be the behaviour of Multiple elements sharing the same positive tabindex value...?

Comment: I don't know the answer because this is a very unusual setup. Are you able to give some more context, eg Why are there elements with positive tabindex values? Is it possible to remove them?

Answer (score 2):

> A positive value means the element should be focusable in sequential keyboard navigation, with its order defined by the value of the number. That is, tabindex="4" would be focused before tabindex="5", but after tabindex="3". If multiple elements share the same positive tabindex value, their order relative to each other follows their position in the document source.

- [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

It should be mentioned that using tabindex should be avoided unless it's absolutely necessary and expected. form elements should follow the natural flow of the document by default (interactive elements have a natural tab order). specifying a tabindex on form items will override the default and can cause major confusion and technical debt. The mozilla page mentioned above includes more information on this.

Answer (score 1):

All elements with the same `tabindex` value are grouped together and the order they are focused to **within that group** is the same as the natural tabbing order.  For "left to right" (LTR) languages, such as English, French, German, etc, the order is left to right and top to bottom.  For RTL languages, such as Arabic or Hebrew, the tab order is right to left (although still top to bottom).

The elements with the smallest **positive** `tabindex` (1) are navigated to first, then the next smallest `tabindex` (2), etc, until no `tabindex` values are left, and then the naturally focusable elements are tabbed to (such as links, buttons, etc).

For example:

```html
<a href="...">a</a>
<a href="..." tabindex="1">b</a>
<a href="..." tabindex="2">c</a>
<a href="..." tabindex="3">d</a>
<a href="..." tabindex="3">e</a>
<a href="..." tabindex="2">f</a>
<a href="..." tabindex="1">g</a>
<a href="...">h</a>
```

- The elements with `tabindex="1"` will be focused first.  There are two of them, B and G.  Since B comes before G in the DOM, B is focused first and then G.
- The elements with `tabindex="2"` will be focused next.  There are two of them, C and F.  Since C comes before F in the DOM, C is focused next and then F.
- The elements with `tabindex="3"` will be focused next.  There are two of them, D and E.  Since D comes before E in the DOM, D is focused next and then E.
- There are no more elements with `tabindex` so everything else is focused next.  A then H.

So the full tab order is B, G, C, F, D, E, A, H

That's an extreme example but shows the order.  You can find all the information in the `tabindex` spec under "[If the value is greater than zero](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/editing.html#ref-for-can-be-focused%E2%91%A6)"

However, if possible, do not use `tabindex` values that are greater than zero.  The [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/editing.html#the-tabindex-attribute) says:

> **Warning!** 
>  Using a positive value for tabindex to specify the element’s position in the sequential focus navigation order interacts with the order of all focusable elements. It is error-prone, and therefore not recommended. Authors should generally leave elements to appear in their default order.